# How to move an Object using Slingshot in different Angles?

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode, game-physics, box2d-iphone

I'm a beginner in iPhone Application Development and Xcode and I'm developing a small game using Box2D which has a slingshot effect. I need help with moving a body in its respective angles when the sling shot is used. The slingshot is drawn using `ccDrawLine` and a body is placed on it.

In my project the object moves haphazardly in different directions when the sling shot is used. Does anyone know how to fix this?

#### My code:

Draw the slingshot:

```
-(void)draw
{
    //NSLog(@"in dra");
    //glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    //glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    //glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    _world->DrawDebugData();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    //glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glColor4f(0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0);
    glLineWidth(4.0f);

    //glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    ccDrawLine( ccp(80, 75),ccp(pt1,pt2));
    ccDrawLine(ccp(pt1,pt2), ccp(240,75));
    ccDrawLine(ccp(80,75),ccp(80,0));
    ccDrawLine(ccp(240,75),ccp(240,0));    
}
```

Place the object on the sling:

```
-(void)addsprite2
{
    stone=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rock.png"];
    stone.position=ccp(160,80);
    stone.tag=1;
    [self addChild:stone];
}
```

I'm trying to create and add the angles manually.

Angle creation:

```
    if (stone.position.y < 80 && stone.position.y >= 70)
    {
        ft = abs(tp2)/PTM_RATIO;
    }
     else if(stone.position.y < 70 && stone.position.y >=60)
    {
        ft = (abs(tp2)+90)/PTM_RATIO;
    }

    else if(stone.position.y < 60 && stone.position.y >= 50)
    {
        ft = (abs(tp2)+110)/PTM_RATIO;
    }

    else if(stone.position.y < 50 && stone.position.y >= 40)
    {
        ft = (abs(tp2)+140)
```

Comment: it sounds like you are on the right path. please post some sample code and we will be able to understand where you are going wrong. You can also check this out. http://www.rodedev.com/tutorials/gamephysics/

Comment: How do i add source code here? Can i Attached a file?

Comment: It seems like your problem is with the motion of the object. But it's hard for me to understand what section of the code that is. You can also look at this to learn how to format code for this website. Don't give up. We're getting close.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have created the slingshot using the Drawline feature and placed an object in the center of the slingshot. I have applied the coding for force to that object. However when i pull and let go of the sling the object moves haphazardly. Now i have added few things about my code. i will waiting for ur reply.

Comment: @Reddevil : Hi..! would you please share code of slingshot with us. i am also in search of something like slingshot in box2d.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bezier curve to implement the projectile curve effect in a 2D space.
Then set the the first and second control points and the end point depending on the pull distance.

This is the simplest way to implement the projectile curve.

Also to move the object you may use touchesMoved function and set the position of the object as the same as that of the touchesMoved point.

```
object.position = pulling.position;
```

This will allow you to move the object as you move your finger.